# Using dplyr summarise_each() with is.na()

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to wrap some dplyr magic inside a function to produce a data.frame that I then print with xtable.

The ultimate aim is to have a dplyr version of [this](http://gettinggeneticsdone.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/summarize-missing-data-for-all.html) working, and reading around I came across the very useful `summarise_each()` function which after subsetting with `regroup()` (since this is within a function) I can then use to get all columns parsed.

The problem I've encountered (so far) is with calling `is.na()` from within `summarise_each(funs(is.na))` as I'm told `Error: expecting a single value`.

I'm purposefully *not* posting my function just yet but a minimal example follows (NB - This uses `group_by()` whilst in my function I replace this with `regroup()`)...

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
> t <- data.frame(grp = rbinom(10, 1, 0.5),
                a = as.factor(round(rnorm(10))),
                b = rnorm(10),
                c = rnorm(10))
t %>%
group_by(grp) %>%  ## This is replaced with regroup() in my function
summarise_each(funs(is.na))
Error: expecting a single value
```

Running this fails, and its the call to `is.na()` that is the problem since if I instead work out the number of observations in each (required to derive the proportion of missing) it works...

```
> t %>%
group_by(grp) %>%  ## This is replaced with regroup() in my function
summarise_each(funs(length))
Source: local data frame [2 x 4]

  grp a b c
1   0 8 8 8
2   1 2 2 2
```

The real problem though is that I do not need just `is.na()` within each column, but the `sum(is.na())` as per the linked example so what I really would like is...

```
> t %>%
group_by(grp) %>%  ## This is replaced with regroup() in my function
summarise_each(funs(propmiss = sum(is.na) / length))
```

But the problem is that `sum(is.na)` doesn't work as I expect it to (likely because my expectation is wrong!)...

```
> t %>%
group_by(grp) %>%  ## This is replaced with regroup() in my function
summarise_each(funs(nmiss = sum(is.na)))
Error in sum(.Primitive("is.na")) : invalid 'type' (builtin) of argument
```

I tried calling `is.na()` explicitly with the brackets but that too returns an error...

```
> t %>%
+ group_by(grp) %>%  ## This is replaced with regroup() in my function
+ summarise_each(funs(nmiss      = sum(is.na())))
Error in is.na() : 0 arguments passed to 'is.na' which requires 1
```

Any advice or pointers to documentation would be very gratefully received.

Thanks,

slackline

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a possibility, tested on a small data set with some `NA`:

```
df <- data.frame(a = rep(1:2, each = 3),
                 b = c(1, 1, NA, 1, NA, NA),
                 c = c(1, 1, 1, NA, NA, NA))

df
#   a  b  c
# 1 1  1  1
# 2 1  1  1
# 3 1 NA  1
# 4 2  1 NA
# 5 2 NA NA
# 6 2 NA NA


df %>% 
  group_by(a) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(sum(is.na(.)) / length(.)))
#   a         b c
# 1 1 0.3333333 0
# 2 2 0.6666667 1
```

And because you asked for pointers to documentation: The `.` refers to each piece of the data, and is used in some **Examples** in `?summarize_each`. It is described in the **Arguments** section of `?funs` as a "dummy parameter" , and is used the **Examples**. The `.` is also briefly described in the **Arguments** section of `?do`: "`...` You can use `.` to refer to the current group"

Comment: Excellent, thanks for that.  I've come across the `.` before as it was used to denote variables that should be converted to factors in `plyr()` and I've seen it used in some `dplyr()` examples. The thing I find confusing (but will bear in mind now) is that many commands work without having to use it to refer to the current group and its not always clear which ones do/don't need it. Anyway, this works great within the function I'm working on, thanks again.